# these are the people or this is the people?

Tags: grammaticality, orthography, formality

In the following paragraph, it is correct to write: ...that this is the people who I want to learn from? or instead it should be.... that these are the people who I want to learn from?

The high level of importance that the government and average people have given to climate change, waste water treatment, and renewable energies make me realize that this is the people who I want to learn from.

Comment: Your example has several errors and it is not clear what you are saying. You *seem* to be using the word "people" in two different senses: The first should be "the government and average **person**; the second "people" seems to mean "nation" as it combines the government and the people.

Answer (score 0):

"This is the people" is very unusual although it appears in the King James version of Bible.

EDIT - see comment by @Greybeard

> Jeremiah 52:28 KJV This is the people whom Nebuchadnezzar carried away
> captive: in the seventh year three thousand Jews and three and twenty
> KJV: King James Version

---

In every other circumstance, including your example, you should say "These are the people", referring to a set of individuals.

Comment: Jeremiah does not refer to an entire population. The Exile (both) concerned quite a limited number of citizens, rather than the whole population. The language of KJV is not currently how it would be expressed and is somewhat misleading. See, e.g. NIV "This is the number of people" where "people" is the plural or "person".

Comment: Thanks for the comment - interesting - I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

"This is the people" *might* be appropriate when "people" is referring to a particular ethnic group, religion, etc.  (A lot depends on context and the nature of the group.)

"These are the people" is generally more idiomatic and would be used to refer to any designated group of people.

In your example "people" is not referring to a coherent and recognized group, and so "this" would not be appropriate.

Comment: This is the complete paragraph: I want to study in Germany because it is a country well-known for the quality of its job in all fields, but mainly in the environmental sphere. The high level of importance that the government and average people have given to climate change, waste water treatment, and renewable energies make me realize that this is the people who I want to learn from